# easy layout for graphic border in css? how to stop misaligned border graphics?

Tags: css, layout, html, border

CSS is not one of my strong points! I'm trying to find a tutorial or something that will give me a premade div and css arrangement if I have a repeating top, left,bottom, right and corners graphic. I feel like I'm getting just close enough but then something breaks horribly. I don't want to use the new css3 implementation.

edit: SOrry for being unclear. I just want to use an image as a border. I have a graphic for the topleft,topright,bottomleft,bottom right, and repeating left and right and top and bottom graphics. I thought that HTML tables were deprecated so I stayed away from them, but I still have problems aligning the border correctly. I'll either have little gaps inbetween somehow, and/or I can't force the border to repeat only every X pixels so the corner graphics line up with the top/bottom and left/right graphics.

Edit: I got pretty close, but there are still ugly problems with the repeating graphic not starting or ending in the right place, and getting the background of the inside to be a solid color behind the png transparency. I'll post what I have.

```
<div id="box">

        <div id="tl"><div id="tr"><div id="top"></div></div></div>
        <div id="left"><div id="right"><div id="content">
            test text
        </div>
        </div></div>
        <div id="bl"><div id="br"><div id="bottom"></div></div></div>
</div>
```

my css:

```
#top {background: url(top.png) repeat-x; width:79%}
#bottom {background: url(bottom.png) repeat-x;height:58px;width:auto;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:79%;}
#left {background: url(left.png)  repeat-y}
#right {background: url(right.png) repeat-y 100% 100%}
#bl {background: url(corner4.png) 0 100% no-repeat;height:55px;margin-left:-6px;}
#br {background: url(corner3.png) 100% 100% no-repeat;height:55px;}
#tl {background: url(corner1.png) 0 0 no-repeat;height:55px;}
#tr {background: url(corner2.png) 100% 0 no-repeat;height:55px; }
```

Comment: Hi there, might be useful for folks here if you explained what effect you're trying to achieve, as it sort of looks like whatever you're doing now is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: You could try asking your question on doctype.com, which is intended for web design questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... got it. Well, does your container have fixed width? If yes....

- Create one image for the top which extends across the entire container. Put that image as a normal image inside your container in the HTML, as the first element.
- Create another image for the bottom which extends across the entire container. Put this image as a normal image inside your container in the HTML, as the last element.
- Create a horizontal background image (1 pixel high) which extends across the entire container and use CSS repeat-y. This gives you the sides for any height container.

... What you'll end up with is something like:

```
<div with background image>
   <top image>
       <your content>
   <bottom image>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there no good solution for non fixed width? I'm worried that the design will look bad on some displays if there is too much blank space.

Comment: Well... if you wanted four corner images (i.e. flexible width), you could do what I've explained above, but treat the top image and bottom image as mini-containers, where you then separately define a right image and left image (floated to each side), and use a vertical background image with repeat-x to give you the flexible width....... I know, it's a lot of hassle for one nonsense box. Maybe someone else knows of a better solution with pure HTML/CSS.